# Delete all text in line before/after highlighted search pattern

Tags: search, vim

I know in VIM how to search a string and delete the text till the start/end of line but I would like to know if it is also possible to delete all text in line before or after highlighted search pattern.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to do this across all lines and don't want to retype your search term I'd suggest the following:

```
:%s/.*\ze<Ctrl-r>///
```

What this does is:

- `%s/`: substitute across all lines in a file
- `.*`: match any character
- `\ze`: end matching so the rest of the pattern is not substituted
- `<Ctrl-r>/`: insert text from the  '/' register (which is the search register)
- `//`: replace with nothing

Edit: Forgot about the after part.  My suggestion to remove both at the same time would be:

```
:%s/.*<Ctrl-r>/.*/<Ctrl-r>//
```

Comment: thank you Randy. Your code `:%s/.*\ze<Ctrl-r>///` works fine. Do you know what to do if there are 2 matches on a line, how to choose the first match or last match?

Comment: If there are only two matches and you want to only change up to the first one you can change the '.*' to a '.\{-}' which changes that match to be non-greedy.  If you want to remove the text between the two matches then you'd probably have to make some major changes to the regex.

Answer (score 13):

To delete the text before FOO on the same line:

`:s/^.*\(FOO\)/\1/`

Comment: how to delete everything after the pattern?

Comment: should be ``:s/\(FOO\).*$/\1/``. The ( must be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

From beginning of line to the beginning of highlighted search pattern: `0dn`

From after end of highlighted search pattern to the end of line: `$N//e<Enter>lD`

These will work in most of the cases.

Comment: thank you, do you know ho to put this in a command for all lines?

Comment: @Remonn: you can put it in a recursive macro and execute it like follows: `ggqqqqq//b<Enter>$N//e<Enter>lD<Enter>0@qq@q`. But again, too simplistic to work in all cases; will fall short in some corner cases. The answer by @Randy Morris contains the way that is *designed* to work, so you'll definitely want to use that if you want to perform the change for multiple lines rather than a single specific line.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on other answers, so I answer here, but I am referring to the answer from xofon:
Just add a '%' in the command line, which would make do for all lines in a file.

delete all chars after ']' in all lines

```
:%s/\(\]\).*$/\1/
```

delete all chars before ' -- ' in all lines in a file

```
:%s/^\( -- \).*/\1/
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete all text in the line line both before and after the search match you could also do:

```
:g//norm gnd0PlD
```

This executes normal mode commands on all lines that match the last search pattern. The commands are `gn` to select the match, `d` to delete it, `0P` to paste it at the beginning of the line, `l` to move to the left (after the text that was just pasted) and `D` to delete until the end of the line. I'm given to understand `gn` is a fairly recent addition to vim, so YMMV.